# If div empty append not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which can contains n divs inside of it but can also be empty. If the div is empty, this can either be on load when there are no items in it, or when a user deletes the items in it by clicking close, a message such as "You have selected 0 items" should appear.

My idea was to try this with:

```
if ($('.container').length == 0) {
    $(this).append('<p class="empty">You have selected 0 items</p>');
};
```

but this is not working? What am i doing wrong?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/Nj5vx/1/

Comment: `.fadeOut()` != `remove()`

Comment: What do you think `this` is? and what do you think `.length` is checking? Do you realize that if is not in the click event?

Comment: you are trying to get all those divs having class .container. which is 1 (according to your fiddle). so .length ==1 and not 0, its working, change your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- fadeOut is asynchronous
- you need to update the list each time am item is removed

http://jsfiddle.net/charlesbourasseau/Nj5vx/3/

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.item').fadeOut(200, function() {
        $(this).remove();
        update();
    });

});

var update = function() {
    if ($('.container div').length == 0) {
        $('.container').append('<p class="empty">You have selected 0 items</p>');
    };
};
```

Comment: This may be the case but the update function is wrong. See the answers below.

Comment: @War10ck actually it's not - he is selecting the children although selecting `.item` would be better...

Comment: Thanks, really like this solution as all items can also be cleared together from another button, for which i can reuse the update var. Also added update(); to execute on load to get the message when container is empty on load.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `$('.container')`, that selects the `<div>` element with the class `container` on it, and returns a jQuery object that contains that element. When you access its `length` property, you're getting the number of elements that matched, not the number of elements within those elements.

What you want instead is:

```
$('.container .item').length
```

That will select the elements with the class `item` inside the element with class `container`. If the `.container` element is empty (has no `.item` elements), then the `length` property will be `0`.

Comment: @Christoph I honestly didn't look in much detail at the fiddle, but yes there seem to be other issues with it that he'd need to correct.

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for your explanation, I see what went wrong now. Added hide() in stead of fadeOut() as well.

Answer (score 2):

Check my jsFiddle of the solution http://jsfiddle.net/Nj5vx/4/

What i did is to call a function to remove items then count how many they exists, if zero then show the message:

```
$(".close").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.item').fadeOut(200, function(){
        $(this).remove();
        if ($('.container .item').length == 0) {
            $('.container').append('<p class="empty">You have selected 0 items</p>');
        };    
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Hi Skatox, thanks for your answer. Think this is the shortest you could write this indeed. Will go for charles solution which is similar though can reuse the update(); var on other buttons as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this : http://jsfiddle.net/5Yftg/

```
$(".close").click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.item').fadeOut(200, function () {
        if ($('.container > .item :visible').length == 0) {
            $('.container').append('<p class="empty">You have selected 0 items</p>');
        };
    });
});
```

Since you are hiding the divs, look for visible ones...

Comment: Hi A.V, thanks for your answer. Interesting approach though will go with the solution of charles.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the length of div container. It is always present isn't it?
As I understood, you need to  check the length of items inside. Like this:

```
if ($('.container .item').length == 0) {
    $(this).append('<p class="empty">You have selected 0 items</p>');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The length in this case is referring to a property on the returned `jQuery` object. It tells you how many elements on the page matched your, for lack of a better phrase search criteria:

```
I.E.
'.container .item'
```

In this case, you code is telling jQuery to search the DOM and when you find no elements, append to that no element.